# Насколько важны правки семантики, орфографии и пунктуации?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Наследственность у меня такая - 7 поколений филологов, но я вот выбрал иную стезю :)

Меня "сильно расстраивает", если вопрос задан безграмотно. На мой взгляд, понимание текста очень сильно зависит от семантики, а также правильной пунктуации и, разумеется, орфографии. Поэтому, если у меня есть свободная минута (поехал на электричке, дабы избежать пробок), я правлю чьи-то тексты (иногда, не обижайтесь, потоки сознания).

Допускаю, что авторам текста может быть обидно, что я вмешиваюсь в их сообщения. В научной среде толерантность к ошибкам - нулевая. А здесь? Насколько актуально исправлять "ашипки ачепятки"?

Comment: Обидно, точно нет. Я люблю русский язык, но в силу обстоятельств пользуюсь только здесь и в семье. В остальное время я использую другие языки. Так вот, хочешь или нет, навыки теряются. Я делаю ошибки и если кто-то меня поправит, я буду только рад. Бывают вопросы, что смотреть невозможно и хочется взять красную ручку и поправить все, а конце еще 2 выставить.

Comment: Иногда правлю. Иногда оставляю, "дабы дурь каждого видна была", причем даже если вношу в вопрос изменения (форматирование и т.п.).

Comment: Лично я за любые исправления, независимо от количества символов в диффе, если они корректны. Малое улучшение — тоже улучшение. Особенно для вопросов, которые составляют костяк базы знаний (имеют много просмотров, голосов). Так что мне странно видеть, что порой отклоняют [подобные правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/794534).

Comment: @tocic  согласен, но чтобы редактировать самому без проверок поднакопите репутации до 2к и ваши правки не будут проходить проверку.

Comment: @tocic давно было обсуждение, лень искать.... суть в том, что участники с малой репой таким образом засирают очередь проверок. Что, поменяв черту на тире - стал вопрос яснее? Ни на грамм, зато в очереди появилось больше мусора. Вот когда человек достигнет репутации 2000, то тогда можно было бы и мелки правки вносить.... Хотя опять же, что это в  глобальном смысле даёт? Кроме оргазма училки русского языка?

Answer (score 15):

Если в нормальном вопросе допущено несколько ошибок, их вполне можно поправить.

Если вопрос сформулировал непонятно, можно его привести в приличный вид.

Если же вопрос совсем мусорный, то тратить на него время не стоит.

Answer (score 5):

Я редактирую посты **только по двум причинам**:

1. Правка поможет автору вопроса получить ответ (быстрее либо вообще)
2. Правка поможет будущим посетителям понять этот вопрос или ответ

Никаких других причин для правок не существует.

Меня совершенно не интересует, как автор будет относиться к моей правке. Если ему что-то не понравится, он всегда может поправить свое сообщение "обратно". Я никогда не возвращаюсь к правке поста, поправленного "обратно", либо были внесены другие правки после меня, даже если они мне не нравятся.

Мои правки в основном касаются оформления поста, форматирования кода или исправления опечаток типа "Windows Froms", которые могут навредить поисковым запросам по базе знаний StackOverflow.

Правки грамматики конечно же допускаю и вношу, согласно списку причин, показанному выше.

Добавлю только то, что если вы взялись править вопрос или ответ, исправляйте всё, а не только очепятки - форматирование кода, разбивка текста по абзацам, если автор не справился с Markdown разметкой, и так далее. Правка "наполовину" - плохая правка.

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от того насколько сильно ошибки мешают восприятию данного вопроса.

#### Когда стоит воздержаться от правок

На странице справки посвященной очереди проверок "Предлагаемые правки", одной из причин отклонения правки, является:

> Изменяет грамматику, опечатки или стиль без видимой необходимости.

Что говорит о том, что если автор пропустил одну или две запятые или сделал опечатку, то от правки стоит воздержаться.

---

#### Когда стоит отредактировать вопрос

И наоборот, если Вам при чтении вопроса приходится задумываться о том, что тут написано - вопрос стоит отредактировать.
Основные критерии: это скорость и качество восприятия вопроса.
Если они страдают, то правка уместна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### На практике

На практике же мы наблюдаем следующее:
Не раз замечалось и обсуждалось то, что опытные пользователи(правки которых вступают в силу минуя очереди проверок) нередко злоупотребляют такой возможностью и вносят правки по одному-два символа. По данной теме я помню как минимум два обсуждения на мете (если найду - приложу к ответу)

По головке за такое никто не гладил, но и каких-либо серьезных последствий такого поведения я также не заметил.
На практике наше сообщество достаточно толерантно к незначительным правкам.

#### Личный опыт

Если у меня возникала непреодолимая тяга к правке вопроса при виде незначительного недостатка, я старался тщательно изучить вопрос и найти другие основания для его редактирования.
Как правило, я находил множество других причин для правки вопроса:

- форматрирование и стили
- метки
- орфография и пунктуация

Во многих случаях в сумме удавалось набрать достаточное количество правок, которые значительно улучшали вопрос.

А вот если Вы вдоль и поперёк изучили весь вопрос и не нашли других причин для правок(за исключением одной или двух запятых), то этот вопрос действительно лучше оставить в преждем виде

#### Обиды и отношение к правке моих вопросов

Я честен с собой и знаю что мои тексты с завидной периодичностью содержат ошибки в пунктуации(а кто не без греха?) и чуть реже в орфографии. И я спокойно отнесусь, если кто-то поправит ошибки, которые я допустил.

При этом я нередко натыкался на пользователей, которые в штыки воспринимают все сообщения об ошибках. Но я не думаю, что на них стоит ориентироваться.

Больше всего непонимания встречается при правке первых вопросов пользователей, которые еще не знакомы с моделью stackoverflow. Данные пользователи в принципе не понимают, как какой-то другой пользователь может править их текст.

**В любом случае:** потенциальные обиды априори не должны быть основанием для решения о правке того или иного вопроса.